# Can i run lighthouse batch for desktop pages ... it always runs by default for mobile env

Tags: lighthouse

I am using lighthouse-batch for page performance test for a list of urlss but it does not have a desktop option to run it for dektop pages. It always runs the pages in mobile environment.

the --preset=desktop is not working either

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [lighthouse-batch issue](https://github.com/mikestead/lighthouse-batch/issues/78#issuecomment-1518144189), looks like you need to use `--params "--preset desktop"` or `--params "--preset=desktop"` (seems like either version should work).

Also be aware that lighthouse-batch hasn't been updated in some time and will only run lighthouse up to 8.6.0, which was released in 2021.